# getting enter to page or reload email comes without clicks the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

when clicks contact form page email is getting without clicks submit button and also comes while refresh the page.i wanna to be in same page while clicks submit button

**my html code**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="commentform">
    <fieldset>
        <p class="field"><input type="text" name="author" required value="" placeholder="Name:"/><span class="required"></span></p>
        <p class="field"><input type="text" name="email" required value="" placeholder="email:"/><span class="required"></span></p>
        <p class="field"><input type="text" name="url" required value="" placeholder="Website:"/><span class="required"></span></p>
        <p><textarea name="comment"required value="" placeholder="Your comment:"/>Your comment*</textarea><span class="required"></span></p>
        <p class="comment_submit">
            <input name="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment"/>
            <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='65' id='comment_post_ID'/>
            <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0'/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $author = $_POST["author"]; 
    $email= $_POST["email"];
    $url= $_POST["url"];
    $comment =$_POST["comment"]; 
    $message = "Name :".$author."\n"."Email :".$email."\n"."Website :".$url."\n"."Comment :".$comment;
    $subject ="Visitor Enquiry";
    $to = "name@gmail.com";

    if(mail($to, $subject,$message)) {
        echo "We Received Your enquiry, We'll get back to you soon";
    } 
    else { 
       echo "There were some errors sending enquiry, please try again";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want your form to submit via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). In short, this means using JavaScript to send your form data to the server to be handled by your PHP script, instead of having the browser handle it.

If you're using jQuery, you could use [an AJAX form plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form/) to easily "upgrade" the form to use AJAX. You could also use jQuery's `.serialize()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)) function to convert your form element to an object you can send to the server using jQuery's `$.ajax` function ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). There is a shorthand function `$.post` for doing POST requests as well.

The latter might look something like this:

```
var $form = $('#commentform');
$form.on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Stops the browser submitting the form

    var data = $form.serialize(), // Convert form to JSON object
        postURL = $form.attr('action') // Get the URL of the form's target;

    // Submit the form via AJAX
    $.post(postURL, data, function (data) {
        // Show the response from the server at the top of the form
        $form.prepend('<p class="message">' + data + '</p>');
    });
});
```

You may need to add the current page URL to the `action` attribute on the form.

Your PHP script will need to know that AJAX has been used so it can output just the response message (used in the success callback for the AJAX request). The `X-HTTP-REUESTED-WITH` header can help you do that:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {
        $author = $_POST["author"];
        $email= $_POST["email"];
        $url= $_POST["url"];
        $comment =$_POST["comment"]; 
        $message = "Name :".$author."\n"."Email :".$email."\n"."Website :".$url."\n"."Comment :".$comment;
        $subject ="Visitor Enquiry";

        $to = "name@gmail.com";
        if(mail($to, $subject,$message))
        {
            echo "We Received Your enquiry, We'll get back to you soon";
        }
        else
        { 
            echo "There were some errors sending enquiry, please try again";
        }

        $via_ajax = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest';
        // If requested via AJAX, end the request now so we just send one of the above messages, not an entire HTML page. 
        if ($via_ajax)
        {
            die;
        }
    }

?>
```

(You'll notice I corrected some of your open/close PHP tags. All PHP code must be *inside* `<?php ?>` tags.

**Suggestions for further improvement**

This is just the bare bones of the operation. To create a good user experience, you'll want to show some sort of "loading" state after the form is submitted, so that while the request is going to the server and being processed your user knows something is happening (normally the browser would take care of this by reloading the page and showing a spinner, etc).

You'll also want to validate the input data in some way - you're currently not doing this at all. I would recommend some basic validation such as requiring a value in the email field. You should do this in PHP, and in addition in JavaScript so you can validate user input before the form is even sent to the server.

You might also want to set a class on the outputted message to depending on whether the request succeeded or failed, so that you could e.g. have the message in green if successful, or red if failed.

If you're having trouble implementing these improvements, then the jQuery documentation is a good place to start, or alternatively find or post a question here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

is your code all in one page? you need to separate it - one page is say `contact.php` with the html of the form, its `action` attribute set to say `email.php` where you have your php code to send the email and eventually redirect the user to wherever you want.

if you want the submit to happen without a page reload, you can add any sort of javascript submit you like, but still the above is needed.

Here is a good tutorial in case you are already using with jQuery:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery

Comment: The OP doesn't necessarily need to separate his HTML form and PHP code into separate files. It's a good idea for maintainability and separation of concerns, but it is not the solution to his problem.

Comment: yes this is the problem i tried with separate page its works fine but, i wanna be stay in same page without a page reload please suggest javascript code to solve this problem.Thank you